# Using dplyr to summarize by multiple groups

Tags: r

I'm trying to use dplyr to summarize a dataset based on 2 groups: "year" and "area". This is how the dataset looks like:

```
  Year   Area Num
1 2000 Area 1  99
2 2001 Area 3  85
3 2000 Area 1  60
4 2003 Area 2  90
5 2002 Area 1  40
6 2002 Area 3  30
7 2004 Area 4  10
...
```

The end result should look something like this:

```
  Year    Area Mean
1 2000 Area 1  100
2 2000 Area 2   80
3 2000 Area 3   89
4 2001 Area 1   80
5 2001 Area 2   85
6 2001 Area 3   59
7 2002 Area 1   90
8 2002 Area 2   88
...
```

Excuse the values for "mean", they're made up.

The code for the example dataset:

```
df <- structure(list(
   Year = c(2000, 2001, 2000, 2003, 2002, 2002, 2004), 
   Area = structure(c(1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L), 
   .Label = c("Area 1", "Area 2", "Area 3", "Area 4"), 
   class = "factor"), 
   Num = structure(c(7L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 1L), 
   .Label = c("10", "30", "40", "60", "85", "90", "99"), 
   class = "factor")), 
   .Names = c("Year", "Area", "Num"), 
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

df$Num <- as.numeric(df$Num)
```

Things I've tried:

```
df.meanYear <- df %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  group_by(Area) %>%
  summarize_each(funs(mean(Num)))
```

But it just replaces every value with the mean, instead of the intended result.

If possible please do provide alternate means (i.e. non-dplyr) methods, because I'm still new with R.

Comment: If you want to group by both Year and Area, then do `group_by(Year, Area)` rather than separate `group_by` statements. The result of consecutive `group_by` is the same as if you ran only the last one.

Comment: I think you want `df %>% group_by(Year, Area) %>% summarize(mean = mean(Num))`. In base `R`, you should be able to do: `aggregate(data = df, Num ~ Year + Area, mean)`.

Comment: `df2 <- ddply(df, .(Year, Area), summarize, Mean=mean(Num))` Does this not work in plyr?

Comment: @RTB that's a `plyr` operation, not `dplyr`, but it's equivalent to @JasonAizkalns `dplyr` code.

Comment: Right, I just caught that, thanks!

Comment: Just curious, why aren't people posting these answers as answers?  Because they aren't sure what the OP wants?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
 library(dplyr)
 df <- group_by(df, Year, Area)
 df <- summarise(df, avg = mean(Num))
```

Comment: yes! Didn't realise group_by can be used like that.

Comment: I am curious why it didnt work with piping operator though

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in my code, I fixed it with the `.groups` attribute:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Year,Area) %>%
  summarise(avg = mean(Num), .groups="keep")
```

Also verified with the added example (`as.numeric` corrupted `Num` values, so I used `as.numeric(as.character(df$Num))` to fix it):

```
   Year Area     avg
  <dbl> <fct>  <dbl>
1  2000 Area 1  79.5
2  2001 Area 3  85  
3  2002 Area 1  40  
4  2002 Area 3  30  
5  2003 Area 2  90  
6  2004 Area 4  10
```

Comment: You may read about .groups attribute [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(avg = mean(Num)) , by = .(Year, Area)]
```